# Git fsck for specific folder

Tags: git, data-recovery, fsck

Is it possible to run

```
git fsck
```

For a specific folder when I am sure that the files I have deleted were located under a specific folder in my Mac?

Comment: `git fsck` checks/fixes *repository* (object database), not a filesystem folder.

Comment: Really confusing. Doesn’t check file system yet the `fsck` stands for File System Check. @phd

Comment: 1. Git authors just borrowed well-known abbrev. 2. Real Unix/Linux `fsck` also don't check folders, they check filesystem structures, indexes, links, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Git** doesn't delete the objects, it just removed the reference to it.

The `git-fsck` command verifies the connectivity and validity of the objects in the database.

You can execute the `git-fsck` command on the repository. With the `--unreachable` argument, it will show you the objects that are unreachable i.e unreachable commit , unreachable blob, etc.. After that, you can also use the `git-show` command to see each object. Once you have found which one corresponds to the files you have deleted, you can run `git-stash apply *commit ID*` to apply the commit to your master branch again.